# How to clear the textfield without an id in Selenium in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am a newbie to `Selenium` and this doubt might be basic. I have an input element of type `text` which has some default value but i need to `clear` that value and `insert` a new value.

Can somebody help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How the default value coming on that field?

Answer (score 3):

In webdriver you can use the clear command

```
@d = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://localhost:8080/wd/hub/")
@d.navigate.to <your site>
@d.find_element(:name, "username")
@d.clear() #clears any text that was in the username field
@d.send_keys ("user") #enters the new text
```

Comment: this worked for me @driver.find_element(:name, "username").clear

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you post question with code snippet. Anyhow, short answer.

```
selenium.type("//input[@name='INPUTNAME']","NEW VALUE");
```

Comment: any another way to handle using WebDriver methods?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858366/how-to-type-some-text-in-hidden-field-in-webdriver