# How to access invisible element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, invisible

1. Hover over the element
2. As soon as we hover there will be

   - A text box
   - A Submit button to click

Firstly, I have to `hover` with mouse and then enter the values in the `Textbox` and then click on `Submit` button.

Comment: I think by Invisible you mean hidden, did you try anything ??

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858366/how-to-type-some-text-in-hidden-field-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below code to perform the required operation.

```
// Initializing the action class
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

// Moving to the element
action.moveToElement(<WebElement>).build().perform();

// Entering the text in the text box
action.moveToElement(<WebElement of Textbox>).sendKeys("Text").build().perform();

// Clicking on the submit button
action.moveToElement(<WebElement of submit button>).click().build().perform();
```

or you can combine all the above actions into single action.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(<Element which displayes text box>).moveToElement(<Element of textbox>).sendKeys("Text").moveToElement(<Element of submit button>).click().build().perform();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Karthik, I have tried the above code and it is not working for me.

Comment: @Automater, Yes I mean Hidden and it is only visible when I hover the mouse on it.

Comment: @Jayant, Can you please paste me the error message observed

Comment: @Karthik , Actually there is no error appearing below is how I have implemented the above code. - :  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("panelCaller"));
  WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("txtappid"));
  WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch"));
 
  action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

  action.moveToElement(element1).sendKeys("1149733").build().perform();
 
  action.moveToElement(element2).click().build().perform();

Comment: Are you able to see the actions being performed on the UI?

Comment: @Karthik, there are no actions performed on the UI

Comment: Can you please put some wait before performing the first mouse hover and if possible can you please provide the site which you are trying, so that I will try from my end and will let you know

Comment: @Karthik, I really appreciate you help but the thing which I am working on belongs to the client, I will try putting the wait before the mouse hover

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait before the each actions you perform?

Answer (score 0):

(Amusing you are using java) According to your approach, you should try using `Mouse` to perform mouse over on the element then find element using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Mouse
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Find element first where you want to hover
WebElement hoverElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(byObject));
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)hoverElement).getCoordinates()); //it will perform mouse over on desire element     

//Now after mouse over you can find the desire text box
WebElement textBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(byObject));
users.sendKeys("your value"); //It will set the value on text box

//Now you can find the desire submit button
WebElement submit = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(byObject));
submit.click(); //It will click on submit button
```

**Edited** :- If unfortunately mouse over does not work using `Mouse`, you can use `JavascriptExecutor` to perform mouse over as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {"
                    + "var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');"
                    + "clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);"
                    + "node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);"
                    + "}triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], 'mouseover');", hoverElement);
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: could you please let me know how below will work - builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)hoverElement).coordinates); //it will perform mouse over on desire element, As I am getting error in my code(The field Actions.mouse is not visible ) and (Locatable can not be resolved as a type)

Comment: @Jayant please make sure you are correct imported  as :- `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;`

Comment: I have included all the latest Jar files of Selenium version 2.53.1 but I am still getting error for builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)hoverElement).coordinates)

Comment: @Jayant and import??

Comment: Yeahh done importing the above two org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions; import org.openqa.selenium.internal.Locatable;

Comment: weird!! replace then it to `builder.moveToElement(hoverElement).build().perform();` and let me know..

Comment: Yeah it worked for the mousehover but now I am getting error when it comes to the line where we are finding the text box where it gives an error like below  - Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: txtappid

Comment: @Jayant let me know first after mouse over it will visible or not on the screen?? and try with the updated answer as well

Comment: I was running it on debug mode I dint get the error where the code for mouse over is written but error was there when it was searching for the text box which is only visible when the mouse over is done. Also I was not able to see the the mouse over happening on screen. Let me know if you want me to answer anything else

Comment: @Jayant Yeah I know your mouse over not happening that's why you are not getting element..I have provided you to perform mouse over using `Mouse` interface..I have updated the answer try using `Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)hoverElement).getCoordinates());` to perform mouse over.. See updated answer..:)

Comment: now the error is appearing for the below line Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse(); HasInputDevices can not be resolved as a type

Comment: @Jayant Strange with the problem.. I have provided you a alternate solution using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform mouse over.. try with updated answer and let me know..:)