# Not able to pass value in hidden text field using javascript in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver and trying to automate a text field(Contact Email) which is hidden on the page initially. But when I select a value in the field (Case SubType), Contact Email text box and other fields get appeared on the page and I need to enter the value in my text box Contact Email here. I tried using javascript but it's not working. Please refer the snapshot for getting the clear picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjbVW.png)

Comment: Please provide your **source code as text**. This will allow us to help you.

Comment: problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as example as you are not share anything:

First change the hidden value as text:

```
WebDriver Fdriver=new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)Fdriver;

//change the hidden value as text
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('body')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");

//locate element
driver.findElement("locator value).sendKeys("abcde");
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything in this line:   //change the hidden value as text
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('body')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");

Comment: Let me check first]

Comment: Try this link, it helps me too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858366/how-to-type-some-text-in-hidden-field-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Thanks it helped me... below is the code that worked for me perfectly:  
  Thread.sleep(2000);
       WebElement contactemail = driver.findElement(By.xpath("locator value"));
       JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');", contactemail);
       contactemail.sendKeys("abc");