# How do I click on a drop down menu that is hidden using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on a drop down menu, but since it is hidden, I'm getting the error:

```
could not be scrolled into view
```

I've done some digging and I see that using some JavaScript could help, but I'm not sure how to implement that into my Python script.

```
<div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiSelect-outlined MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input jss987" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-labelledby="input-label-idTeam1Desktop select-idTeam1Desktop" id="select-idTeam1Desktop"><span>​</span></div>
<input name="idTeam1Desktop" type="hidden" id="idTeam1Desktop" value="">
```

This is what I have so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options)
driver.get("https://tradenba.com/trade-machine")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='idTeam1Desktop']")
element.click()
```

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858366/how-to-type-some-text-in-hidden-field-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) article.

Comment: Which item do you want to select? `MIL` or `TOR` or `BOS`?

Comment: Perhaps you could send the `click` action to the parent div of your select input field.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the drop down menu and select the menu item with text as **MIL** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://tradenba.com/trade-machine')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='select-idTeam1Desktop']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='MuiListItemText-root MuiListItemText-inset']/span/div/p[text()='MIL']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tradenba]

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try your method: "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <div id="select-idTeam1Desktop" class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiSelect-outlined MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input jss354"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is 
not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed"

Comment: When I run my script with just the first two lines of your code, I notice that the dropdown menu gets selected and appears, but quickly vanishes.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if you were notified by my previous comments. I really appreciate your help so far! @DebanjanB